# Redirect all subdirectory requests to single file with requested directory intact

Tags: php, lighttpd

I want to have a directory on my lighttpd server that will redirect all requests to a main `index.php` file, but with the PHP to be able to interpret the original request URI.

For example, both `www.server.com/directory/foo` and `www.server.com/directory/bar` would run `www.server.com/directory/index.php`, but the PHP context would be able to see the domain (with something like `$_SERVER['uri']`?) and use an internal PHP router to figure out what to do.

Currently I've tried a few variations on this:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/directory/.*" {
    url.redirect = (
        "^/.*/assets/(.*)" => "/dir/assets/$1",
        "^/.*/(.*)" => "/dir/index.php"
    )
}
```

but the `index.php` is unable to see the original route. The assets thing works though. Thanks!

Comment: I do it on apache2 by redirecting to the PHP script if a file or directory matching the request isn't found.  This kicks in before a 404 is sent to the client, so it is transparent on that end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, in case anybody else needs:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/directory/.*" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^/.*/assets/(.*)" => "/directory/assets/$1",
        "^/[^\?]*(\?.*)?" => "/directory/index.php$1"
    )
}
```

Forwards on any query params as well.